# Xaml TextBlock set round corner

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, textblock

I am trying to set rounded corner of `TextBlock` in `xaml`. But there is no such property.

```
<Grid x:Name="grdDis" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock Text="Description" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="txtDescription" Margin="18,10,0,0" Height="128" Width="445"/>
</Grid>
```

How can I set rounded corner of TextBlock. And also want to set Background color of TextBlock.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use [`Border`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.border):

```
    <Border Margin="5" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" Background="AntiqueWhite" CornerRadius="10">
        <TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum"/>
    </Border>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: ...And what happens when TextBlock has a diferent background color (not transparent) that it is not the same as border background color? In this case I think TextBlock corners will not appear as rounded...

Comment: @Rodri, sorry for late response. It's okay, `Border` and `TextBlock` can handle this correctly. Added the screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

for that use the Border element as a parent of textBlock
as like,

```
 <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Green" CornerRadius="5">
    <TextBlock Text="Description"/>
</Border>
```

you already got it. :)

Comment: As said to Dennis, what happens when TextBlock has a diferent background color (not transparent) that it is not the same as border background color? In this case I think TextBlock corners will not appear as rounded. So in this case, how do you face this problem?

Answer (score 2):

TextBlock do not have such property, however you can do it like this using Rectangle's `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` property by binding the width and height of `Rectangle` to `Textblock` Width and height.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBlock Name="textBlock" Padding="5,0" Text="This is my TextBlock" Height="30" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Rectangle RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" Width="{Binding Width,ElementName=textBlock}" Height="{Binding Height,ElementName=textBlock}" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```